# Deleting a model and all references to it in his relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm still new to Laravel and Eloquent but joining on a project previously built.

I have a User model that have many relationships like for example Actions(HasMany), Roles(BelongsToMany), Type(BelongsTo),..and many others...

What I want to do is to **delete an User model and it's data** and when I'm doing it, **deleting all traces of him in his relations but not the content itself**, basically I want to keep his relations models (Actions, Roles, Type,...) in my database but deleting his FK so that it cannot be linked to my user anymore while keeping the entry previously associated to him.

I tried a few things without success like

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id)
$user->delete();
// This one giving me a SQLSTATE[23000] The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint 

$user->actions()->detach()
// or
$user->actions()->dissociate()
// But undefined for HasMany relations
```

and I was wondering if there was a "clean" and simple way to do it other than updating all those Foreign_Keys to a "NULL" value in each of the relationships

```
$user->userActions()->update(['id_user' => null]);
$user->userRoles()->update(['id_user' => null]);
//...and on and on... before being able to do a 
$user->delete();
```

I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code of your migrations for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the user as:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id)
$user->delete();
```

The problem here is that, you don't want to delete all the information from the user in the other tables. In SQL you define Foreign Keys specially for this purpose so you don't have data in the table that is "lost in space" because it does not relate to anything. This builds (space) the tables with  information that is difficult to access because it's not related to nothing.

For that purpose usually people use "**ON DELETE CASCADE**" to delete all reference (related by FK) in the other tables. If you don't have this you have to manually delete the information in other tables before deleting the user.

My recommendation is rethink why you want to remove the user and keep the data, if you want to keep the data just disable the user, at the end of the day you will want to know the information of the user for the data in the other tables.

I hope this can help and clarify your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the hand on the DB management, but I put in a word about it to the person responsable for it.


What I ended up doing (even though it's not as clean as I wanted to be) is to check each key referenced to my userID and either pass it to null (if I needed to keep that line) or delete the entire entry.

Comment: I honestly don't know the reason why you want to keep the information related to a user and don't keep the user, but the issue is a database engine configuration to help prevent data that is related.

Comment: I agree that the main issue here is the database configuration that need to be modified to allow that changes more easily/cleanly.
As for the need of deleting the user but not some of the related entry is because those entries are used for something else (like for example the 'user' being the current manager of a place, if I delete him I need to change the managerID to 'null' but keep that place in the DB since he will no longer be manager but the place will still existe).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hard Delete, I recommand using the ondelete set null :

```php
Schema::table('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('id_user')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
});

Schema::table('actions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('id_user')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
});
```

No need for model event or managing it yourself, mysql is managing everything for you

Answer (score 0):

You must delete all related records first , then delete the record itself :

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);

$user->actions()->detach();

$user->delete();
```

or you may register closures that execute when various model events are dispatched. Typically, you should register these closures in the booted method of your model :

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::deleting(function ($user) {
            $user->actions()->detach();
        });
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events-using-closures)